# controlling 2 Windows simultaneously for a-b testing

Tags: web-development, testing

I'm searching for an app that is cloning all my commands(mouse and keyboard) to a second window.

Especially for Browsers.
I'd like to test a web page and want to see the different behavior in two windows(different revisions of the page) directly.

For example, in window 1 i click link3 and an a specific url opens.
This should be done automatically in the second window.
If i enter some formula data this should be cloned either.

Is there any application for windows oder linux which serves this desire?

i know that there are command line tools which clone commands in one terminal to several others.

Answer (score 1):

As for Linux - although there are tools to track mouse and keyboard events and send them to windows (xdotool), I would rather try to record a macros and then run it for different versions of the site, because to my opinion relying on x events for a task like visiting links and clicking buttons does not seem reliable enough.

I would try DejaClick Firefox extension for some simple things and consider picking one of tools listed here: http://softwareqatestings.com/software-testing-tools/web-functional-and-regression-test-tools.html for something more complicated.

I am not a web developer (frankly, not a programmer at all), but I use xdotool for different proof-of-concept window control tasks and I believe cloning X events this way leaves a chance for things to go wrong. What if any other window would somehow grab focus during test?

Comment: I like the recording & playback aspect.

Comment: What's more important - you don't depend on window geometry and cursor coordinates this way. I used xdotool to emulate hotkeys in combination with lirc to control file manager with IR remote control, but it was sending key presses to definite window (by name or ID) rather than relying on the fact that the given button is (x,y) pixels right and down from the window corner.